# Stop JavaScript/HTML5 music player from showing media location URL

Tags: audio, mp3, javascript, html5

Is there any way to stop this a HTML5/JavaScript based music player from displaying the location URL of the song it is set up to play from my website server? I have searched for a solution myself, to no avail.

It's the second last script listed here: [Using JavaScript to Control the Audio Object (HTML5)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589489(v=vs.85).aspx)

The title is: Audio playbackRate Example

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnjcv.jpg)

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of what you're seeing when you run that script? The likely answer is no. Even if you did, it would still be in the source with that example.

Comment: Hi Seth thanks for responding, here's what l get from the script. As you can see, the full URL is laid bare!

[Resulting player, with media source URL partly censored]
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQRBn.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your goal is but lets get started with it anyway.

The page you linked contains examples on how to interact with the HTML5 audio element using JavaScript. Depending on what your goal the normal HTML5 audio tag might already be sufficient. See also [Getting Started with the HTML5 Audio Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589529(v=vs.85).aspx) which is linked in the article you linked.

If we take the example code and take a screenshot of the result, the standard (browser dependent) HTML5 audio tag player would be the upper one. The page and script include all of the other parts.

[image: Image of the audio player(s)]

What the actual script does is, that it takes the input from the HTML input element (that contains the file) and assigns it as a source to the audio tag. The article you linked actually has quite a lengthy explanation for this, did you read it?

To actually get rid of the direct display there are multiple options.

- Hide the input using CSS
- Hide the input using JS
- Use another kind of element or piece of code to make it the source of the information about what file to play.

The proper approach would probably be to use part of the JS to get the source instead of having an actual HTML element in the source.

An easy intermittent solution would be to change the type attribute of `<input type="text" id="audioFile" value="__file__" size="60" />` to `type="hidden"`.

The downside would be that you can't just put another file in the input box and let it play (by hand).

Comment: You have actually demonstrated what i want in your screenshot, where it just shows "SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3", without the path. Would be nice to know how you did that, as that's all l'm looking for.

Comment: I want the MP3's file path to be hidden. I just want the MP3's name to appear, not the path. I understand that it is possible to just specify the MP3 name as the path IF the webpage containing the script is located in the same folder as the MP3s. However, l want the same script on multiple webpages in different locations. Therefore what l really want is to just NOT show the file path, that's all l want. I just want MP3 title to display, no path. None of the articles you mentioned show how to do this, and l already had glanced at them. Also, l'm just a guy coming in off the street, no skills.

Comment: I did that by just using a relative path. You could do that for each of your sites (low effort). Alternatively you should start to get a grasp on on how JavaScript works because you'll need it in that case. Essentially you'll need to use a simple string replace (assuming the path to the files remains the same) or you'll need to do it on your backend (again a simple replace) but instead of just one have two inputs. One hidden with the full path and one visible with just the filename.

Comment: Right, so you are aware that l'm a beginner. You seem to think l have multiple sites and other misunderstandings. Sorry for not making it clear, but l just want the song name to display, and l'm just a beginner. If you're not going to help, then please do not get involved as l don't want a treasure quest here.

Comment: `... want the same script on multiple webpages in different locations ...` that is what you said. If you're using an absolute link as you've done (including http etc.) it works regardless of where you place it. If you use a relative link it won't and it seems you have already tried that. The easily solution is to include the whole archive in every single folder that the web page resides in that should have a player. Not what you want to do? Go and learn some JavaScript. It doesn't look like you have spend any time understanding what's written in the example and played around with it.

Comment: The tutorial even directly mentions that `audioElm.src` is what really matters to make this work. Furthermore I even explained to you what you need to do. You will just have to lookup how to handle variables in JS and change the value of a textbox (it's already being read on line 44 so maybe you can write it?). I won't get more explicit than that. You are a beginner? Than start learning about what you want to do instead of having someone do the work for you. You want someone to do the work for you? Pay them or ask very nicely.

Comment: I told you multiple times that you need to setup a variable with the URL (actual variable or hidden input), assign it to the audio element, shorten it to the filename and place that in the input. If you're not able to work this out, you're probably going to run into issues pretty soon. All of the elements for this are in your example. Just as an example you have redundant play elements and you might want to play more than just one song. If you don't figure out how to work with variables you're probably not going anywhere. In addition you're already on a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I haven't a clue what you are talking about and all l wanted was to know how to make the display show MP3 name only, without the filepath. As l explained, l am at a very basic level, and l'm aware that l can just host the songs in the same folder and that way l need only specify the song name, and that is also what will display in the path name, and so in a roundabout way, l will after all be displaying only the song name. However l wanted to tell the script to display "Song Title", and link it to a filepath, but the display will only display "Song Title".

Comment: Please don't confuse the question (= the previous sentence, which amounts to what you are also telling me l should do as a *solution*) with the solution (= how exactly do l do that?). Once again thank you for your help.